# internet disconnects after cloning MAC in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: ubuntu, internet-connection, mac-address, spoofing

Whenever I connect the LAN cable to my new laptop, there is connection, but the web is not accessible due to MAC mismatch (my old laptop's MAC is registered with my ISP). When I spoof the MAC address in Windows, it works just fine. But in Ubuntu 14.10, when I clone the MAC address, the net starts connecting and disconnecting repeatedly (at a frequency of about 20 times per minute). Please help me get over this problem. Thanks in advance. (Btw, I'm a newcomer in Linux).

Comment: Sounds like a driver problem. Can you post the output of `lshw -c network`? Also, in the output, look for a `driver=[driver_name]` in the `configuration` field for your Ethernet controller. Then do `modinfo [driver_name]`. Post the output by editing your question.